# How to get access to the instance variable within the Create event?

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I have this code in GML2 `Create` event

```
inst1 = instance_create_layer(100, 100, "Instances", obj_genus)
inst2 = instance_create_layer(200, 100, "Instances", obj_genus)
with inst1 {
    txt = "Ying"
    related = inst2
}
with inst2 {
    txt = "Yang"
    related = inst1
}
```

But I can't use `inst1` or `inst2` at this time. I get the follower error:

```
ERROR in
action number 1
of Create Event
for object obj_game:

Variable obj_genus.inst2(100006, -2147483648) not set before
reading it.
at gml_Object_obj_game_Create_0(line 5)-     related = inst2
##################
gml_Object_obj_game_Create_0 (line 5)
```

I create pairs of objects which are related to each other. Is it possible to wait in the `Create` event, until the object has been created? Unfortunately there is no `Post Create` event or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not related to instance creation, but rather to the `with` statement - see, `with` changes what the current instance will be in the block, therefore as of `related = inst2` line you are not pulling the `inst2` variable from `obj_game`, but rather from `obj_genus` that you apply the statement on.

Using local variables (which you have found yourself) is by far the easiest way around this, as local variables are function/event-wide and thus remain perfectly accessible inside a `with`-block.

If you do need those two instances stored in `obj_game` for later use, you could use `other.`:

```
inst1 = instance_create_layer(100, 100, "Instances", obj_genus)
inst2 = instance_create_layer(200, 100, "Instances", obj_genus) // stores inst2 in obj_game
with inst1 {
    txt = "Ying"
    related = other.inst2 // uses inst2 from obj_game
}
with inst2 {
    txt = "Yang"
    related = other.inst1
}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that difference

Answer (score 3):

In addition to YellowAfterlife's comment, this situation probably could avoid using the "with" construct entirely, and you could get away with this instead:

```
inst1 = instance_create_layer(100, 100, "Instances", obj_genus)
inst2 = instance_create_layer(200, 100, "Instances", obj_genus)
inst1.txt = "Ying"
inst1.related = inst2
inst2.txt = "Yang"
inst2.related = inst1
```

You're correct that there isn't anything like post-create event, and how you are doing it is the correct and standard way of passing data to an instance.

(On a side note I highly recommend getting in the habit of putting a semicolon **;** at the end of every line. GML is pretty forgiving and usually lets you skip it, but most languages aren't, including GLSL which is how you program shaders in both GMS1 and 2.)

Comment: I am fine with the `with`-blog, because I will set more fields. Only for my question I wanted to make it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that it will work fine when is use `var`. I have no idea why it is so. `var` means that a variable is only available in this event and will be deleted when the event finished.

```
var inst1 = instance_create_layer(100, 100, "Instances", obj_genus)
var inst2 = instance_create_layer(200, 100, "Instances", obj_genus)
with inst1 {
    txt = "Ying"
    related = inst2
}
with inst2 {
    txt = "Yang"
    related = inst1
}
```

Comment: `var` is indeed used to use instances you've just created. It's true that you can no longer access the instance through the var after this Event, but the instance will still exist afterwards. I don't think I've managed to get objects stored in another instance, but it is possible to find their related objects through unique objects, or ID's.